# Out Of memory in Jmeter response

Tags: out-of-memory, jmeter

I am doing load test on my web service.My web service will return response as Images.

So when I am submitting the request to fetch 100K images from my web service I am getting Out Of memory error in Jmeter

**jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse**

I increased heap size in Jmeter.bat file but still facing the same issue.

Is there any way to not handle the response(releasing response images from memory) in Jmeter and generate summary report.

Comment: 100K images! what are you doing with those many images? What is average size of those images?

Comment: Are you using GUI version of jmeter ? If yes try to use command line version. It is much more memory efficient and you can launch your test plans as well using: jmeter -n -t your_test_plan.jmx

Comment: we do some processing with those images. max size of image can be 2mb @Nachiket Kate